# Unable to execute bash script from a loadable kernel module

Tags: bash, debugging, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to execute a bash script in the user space using the call_usermodehelper function like this.

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */                                
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
#include<linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h> 
   
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
   
static char *mystring = "blah"; 
   
module_param(mystring, charp, 0000); 
MODULE_PARM_DESC(mystring, "A character string");

static int __init hello_start(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading rooted module...\n");
    pr_info("mystring is a string: %s\n", mystring); 
    char* argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "home/grim-reaper/kernel/FocusModule/focusmyman.sh", NULL};
    static char* envp[] = { "HOME=/",  "TERM=linux",   "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };
    call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_end(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "exit.\n");
    char* argv[] = {"/bin/bash", "home/grim-reaper/script-remove.sh", NULL};

    static char* envp[] = { "HOME=/",  "TERM=linux",   "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL };
    call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_EXEC);
}

module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

The shell script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f ~/kernel/FocusModule/focus.txt ]; then
    echo "File exists and is a regular file"
else
    touch focus.txt
fi


while true; do
    active_window=$(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)
    
    echo "$active_window" >> ~/kernel/FocusModule/focus.txt    
    sleep 5
done
```

This script works perfectly when executed in the terminal, but it simply doesn't start execution when called from the module. The module compilation and `dmesg` show no errors. I'm at a loss at what's wrong. Please help. I've used an identical module for the execution of another script, which has just a `chmod` command, and it works perfectly.

Comment: I would make the path to `home/grim-reaper/kernel/FocusModule/focusmyman.sh` a full path starting with `/`.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that and path starting with ~/ but to no avail.

Comment: What about trying `sh -c "home/grim-reaper/kernel/FocusModule/focusmyman.sh` from the module to see if it works? `sh -c` should spawn a new shell to run in.  Maybe ENV problem??

Comment: Here is an example using `sh -c`:  https://tech.feedyourhead.at/content/kernel-programming-execute-call-usermodehelper-within-a-systemcall

Comment: Note, that using `UMH_WAIT_EXEC` means that `call_usermodehelper` call doesn't wait that the process will *complete* its execution. It is better to use `UMH_WAIT_PROC` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385836/why-does-call-usermodehelper-fail-most-of-the-times.